# Cocos2d How to draw 3D images and rotate?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

i am new in objective c and in my application i have to draw the 3D image(like carton boy) and rotate it in X axis,Y axis and z axis by using OpenGL ES framework How can i draw the images.someone help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making a 3D game in cocos2d project then the 3D parts will have to be loaded using either another framework (like cocos3d) or like you said using OpenGL framework.

cocos3D http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/ works easily with cocos2d and will allow you to load 3d objects and use them in the way you want.

OpenGL framework will be more difficult to understand and use but will give you more flexibility depending on the results you want.

I would solve your question by creating 3D objects in a open source (and free) software like [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) and load them in a cocos3d project, from there, the way to manipulate them the way you want is fairly easy.